# Silex - Guzzle call to external API

Tags: php, symfony2

I'm at the point where I am happy with the functionality of my code but I dislike how its written. It seems like I can be more modular with it but I can't seem to figure out how to improve on it without changing to much. I understand that I can probably merge both getMed Methods but they are end points in a URL which I rather keep separate. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

```
private function getSIS($url, $session, Application $app)
{
    $response = "You don't have permission to access this!";

    if($app['security']->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'))
    {
        //['fomservices']['sis'] is hard coded in my config dev/prod file.
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $app['fomservices']['sis'],]);
        //for testing
        $token = 123456;

        try {
            if (!empty($session)) {
                $response = $client->request('GET', $url.'/'.$session, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'token' => $token
                    ]
                ]);
            } else {
                $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'token' => $token
                    ]
                ]);
            }
            return $response;
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            return new Response($responseBodyAsString, $response->getStatusCode());
        } catch (ServerException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            return new Response($responseBodyAsString, $response->getStatusCode());
        } catch (BadResponseException $e){
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            return new Response($responseBodyAsString, $response->getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    return $response;
}

public function getMedAction(Application $app)
{
    $response = $this->getSIS('med', '', $app);
    if($response instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)
        return $response->getBody();
    return new Response ($response);
}

public function getMedSessionAction($session, Application $app)
{
    $response = $this->getSIS('med', $session, $app);
    if($response instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)
        return $response->getBody();
    return new Response ($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to improve on my previous code by making sure all the return statements were returning the same type of response `(String / StatusCode)`. This allowed the 20 methods calling this one must smaller since I didn't have to check what response contain.

```
private function getSIS($url, $session, Application $app)
{
    if($app['security']->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'))
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $app['fomservices']['sis']]);
        $token = 234561;

        // Calling the external API which multiple errors could occur.
        try {
            if (!empty($session)) {
                $response = $client->request('GET', $url.'/'.$session, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'token' => $token
                    ]
                ]);
            } else {
                $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'token' => $token
                    ]
                ]);
            }
            return new Response($response->getBody(), 200);
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            return new Response($response->getBody()->getContents(), $response->getStatusCode());
        } catch (ServerException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            return new Response($response->getBody()->getContents(), $response->getStatusCode());
        } catch (BadResponseException $e){
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            return new Response($response->getBody()->getContents(), $response->getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    return new Response("You don't have permission to access this!", 401);
}

public function getMedAction(Application $app)
{
    return $this->getSIS('med', '', $app);
}

public function getMedSessionAction($session, Application $app)
{
    return $this->getSIS('med', $session, $app);
}
```